# Trouble converting int -> ascii -> int in Java

Tags: java, int, ascii

I wrote these functions to write int values to a file using the least number of bytes possible. But one line is reading the wrong value for some reason (see comment).

```
File f = new File("data.txt");
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");

raf.writeBytes(toByte(4321,3)); // convert 4321 to ascii
raf.seek(0);
System.out.println(fromByte(raf.readLine())); // convert back

// convert integer to ascii String for i < 16,777,216
// let b=1 for i<256, b=2 for i<256*256, b=3 for i<256*256*256
private static String toByte(int i, int b){
    if (b==3) // 3 bytes
        return "" + (char)(i/65536) + (char)(i%65536/256) + (char)(i%256);
    if (b==2) // 2 bytes
        return "" + (char)(i/256) + (char)(i%256);
    else      // 1 byte
        return "" + (char)i;
}

// convert ascii string to integer for s.length = {1,2,3} 
private static int fromByte(String s){
    int i = 0;
    if (s.length()==3)
        i = (int)s.charAt(0)*65536 + 
            (int)s.charAt(1)*256 + 
            (int)s.charAt(2);//------------> 65533? should be 225!
    else if (s.length()==2)
        i = (int)s.charAt(0)*256 + 
            (int)s.charAt(1);
    else
        i = (int)s.charAt(0);
    return i;
}
```

Output is 69629, but should be 4321.

Comment: This happens because you read file as UTF. Add reading/writing code to your question.

Comment: The individual characters of a Java string are UTF-16 code units (16 bit integers). This makes the conversions behave odd if any of the ASCII characters has a value > 127.

Comment: Also, new String probably interprets its byte array argument as UTF-8 (or UTF-16, but most likely not ASCII)

Comment: @Michael is there a way to specify 8-bit characters? I assumed that casting unsigned 8-bit values to char would use ascii, and I tried `x = (x<0? x+=128 : x)` but that didn't help.

Comment: `char` is 16 bits long in Java. You should use `byte` here.

Comment: @JonahM: ASCII is actually a 7-bit encoding. The 8-bit-encoding that shares its code space with the first 256 code points of Unicode (and therefore also the first 256 code points of UTF-16 a.k.a. Java char's), is called latin1 or ISO-8859-1. So what you are trying to do is convert a byte array to a String by interpreting it as latin1-encoded. -- The next thing is: the `new String(byte[])` docs say "Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset" - which is probably UTF-8. It is not converting each byte individually to char.

Comment: @JonahM: after your latest edit your code works for me and prints 4321. System is macOS 10.14.4, java version "1.8.0_45".

Comment: thats because [RandomAccessFile.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine()) is specified to use latin1-encoding.

Comment: You want character set `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1` because it converts every character code between 0..255 to a byte value 0..255 and vice versa. It's the only character set with this property.

Comment: A typical approach to this goal would be to serialize all the integers as the same width (32, 16, or 8 bits—whichever is needed), and zip it. [Reposted to correct typo: -> width]